# finding triplets with O(n+k) time complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity

The function gets a list of not negative integers and it must find the numbers that are 3 times exactly inside the list. (the value of the integers are between `0` to `k-1`), then create a new list with all the triplets found.

I'm having a hard time understanding the `O(n+k)` time complexity, I went with, if k is bigger than n then it will be `O(k)` and the opposite, and tried to write this code for the first case (`k>n`):

```py
def k_bigger_than_n(lst, k): # a function that works in case k is bigger than n
    triplets = []
    for i in range(int(k+1)):
        count=0
        if (i in lst): # checks if in list first time
            count += 1
            lst.remove(i)
            if (i in lst): # checks if its in list again (2 repetitions)
                count += 1
                lst.remove(i)
                if(i in lst): # checks if theres 3 repetitions of i
                    count+=1
                    lst.remove(i)
                    if(i in lst): #in case theres more than 3 its no longer added to our triplets.
                        count=0
        if(count==3):
            triplets.append(i)
            triplets.append(i)
            triplets.append(i)
    return triplets
```

I was wondering if the `in` that I used in my `if` statements ruin my time complexity, or if I understood the time complexity of `O(n+k)` right.

Any explanation is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you allow for space complexity to be O(k), then it takes O(n+k) time to solve. n to iterate the array and O(k) to initiate the counter array that finally find the elements with count as 3.

Comment: Space complexity can be whatever, the thing i am thinking about if the (in) checks and compares every element in my list then thats o(n) inside a for thats o(k) , which becomes o(k*n) and not o(n+k), what do you think?

Comment: Yes, your complexity is O(n * k). One way to have O(n log n) complexity is to sort numbers and then iterate over them and count number of occurances of adjacent numbers, then complexity will be just the complexity of sorting function which is O(n log n).

Comment: Another way to have O(n) complexity but with quite big constant inside is to use `dict()` to count occurances.

Comment: @Arty thanks for the idea about sorting the numbers before iterating over them, but does have O(n log n) mean its still O(n+k)? I can't get the idea of the k being in the time complexity

Comment: If you want to achieve O(n + k) complexity then just use counting `dict()`, it will give O(n) complexity.

Comment: Just went and read what is dict() in python, seems like a good idea, if I convert my list to a dict at the start of the function, each one of the (in) checks will have O(1) complexity? thus leading to a o(k) total?

Comment: @Pwaol I created [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370923/941531) with simple `dict()` solution for you.

Comment: @Pwaol If you convert to dict your list you still will have O(n) complexity. You can't ever have less than O(n) just because you have to look at all 100% of list elements at least once to figure out if there are no more triples. And because you have to look at `n` elements at least once that means you have at least O(n) complexity always. Conversion to dictionary itself will be already O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next code will have `O(n)` complexity, it uses `dict()`. You can't have less complexity because you have to look at all elements at least once to figure out which of remaining numbers may still form a triple. All you can do is to have bigger or smaller constant-multiplier inside `O(n)`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7RCsIwDEXf9xX3scUynJsIQr9kDB@2VMtmN7ooiPjttWZPhsslycmFLC@@zaFOaSAH58Nw4eiXiXhVkz4XyNXD4v2R1s0RBB8wbUhwS12@6MsrsSKDvcYOleBI/IgB7SjB0eD5y/alZ7qvSsO7vLEWdVcUS/SB1f8H7cngYJC9Fq9kzGoMjqJmU6d1Sl8)

```
def find_triplets(l):
    c = {}
    for e in l:
        c[e] = c.get(e, 0) + 1
    return [k for k, v in c.items() if v == 3]

print(find_triplets([7, 2, 7, 3, 7, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4]))
```

Output:

```
[7, 2]
```

**PS**. Just for curiosity I provide algorithm with exactly `O(n + k)` complexity in [this online snippet](https://tio.run/##VU/RCsIwDHzfV@SxxTLUTQTBLxlDxpbN4MxKV0ERv73GTp2WIyS94y6xN38cOAuhwRZa4ubgHdke/ah6vUtAXg17uD9i2w4OEIihn6hIF1iKok479AoNLDUsYBXp05nYSK2uIpBe1ekJb6PS2oB8zmNUOxxFVpTfJHoluYo7VD9OYq7ndGonWQ0VN7ILyS57yGbB2zmtrEVuFH2y/MXxi0gS64i9@r@92BpYG5CaxbqKoyA3sInIJ5Rah/AE) although it is not as efficient as `O(n)` algorithm above. And another `O(n log n)` algorithm using sorting I [implemented here](https://tio.run/##dZBRCsIwEET/c4rxr8Ug1lYEIVfwAqWItCkGyiak6Yenr5uolYIOw0L2sbNL3CPcLZXz3OkevaHuGrxxgw5jNuRnAVY7eYmWgoTXIxQulrTEXqJuEu@th4EhjNYH3S1zUaZntFEx49t8A46EUijXIIr37G7OaeoyHsxX/HMNH2L4ioXF1lahEH/Tf6V6HSZPEQnhvKGQrf@gPkkcJLiWqRbpya4kjsnVy02ez/MT). Also another `O(n + k)` algorithm using counting-sorting array [here online](https://tio.run/##VY5BCsIwFET3PcUsG5uFtRVByElCkNImGNKmIaaip4/x142fx8AMM/DDO91X3@U8aQNj/XRL0YZZp0c9s2uFcg4Cy/AqHg1aisYSyaPCAY68WSMsrMe8T6gjrUIjfouo0xY9pKOu43h@69pvi45D0vXIYE0JhUCnqipE61P9/4@8cJw4inakLdlCz3Em@h3FWM4f).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! tbh I'm still new to this and have never used dicts before and I'm struggling to understand your code, can you explain what the 4th and 5th lines do? and does O(n) complexity mean its O(n+k)? sorry about asking too much questions and thanks for bearing with me

Comment: @Pwaol Complexity O(n) is less (meaning more faster) than O(n + k). If your task is to achieve at least O(n + k) complexity, then my solution has achieved, because anything faster than O(n + k) is enough. I.e. O(n + k) solution will take more time than O(n) solution for big enough `n`, meaning that starting from some `n` (e.g. 1000) all bigger `n` will give longer time for O(n + k) than O(n).

Comment: @Pwaol To comment line by line my code. First we create a dictionary `c = {}`, this dictionary maps from numbers to count of occurances. Then `for e in l` iterates over all elements of list. Then `c[e] = c.get(e, 0) + 1` increments counter by `1`, first gets current value of counter with fallback to 0 (`c.get(e, 0)`), fallback means that if there is no such value inside dictionary for number `e` then `c.get(e, 0)` returns value `0`. So `c[e] = c.get(e, 0) + 1` increments counter for number `e` by `1`.

Comment: @Pwaol Last line `[k for k, v in c.items() if v == 3]` is a so-called list comprehension, it creates a resulting list that contains all such numbers `k` such that theirs counter `v` inside dictionary is equal to 3 (`if v == 3`). Expression `c.items()` returns all pairs `(key, value)` that are contained inside dictionary, dictionary always contains mapping from some keys to some values of any type, in our case dictionary contains mapping from a number (key) to counter (value).

Comment: @Pwaol So yes O(n) complexity is also O(n + k), in fact O(n) is faster than O(n + k) for quite large `n`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have just taught me alot of new stuff and your explanation makes it all clear. if the question asks for exactly O(n+k) complexity I can just find the maximum number in my list using `max(list` and make a loop that goes from zero to it and does nothing to add more and make it O(n+k) time complexity?

Comment: @Pwaol If you want to create exactly O(n + k) algorithm then first do counting like in my code inside `for` loop, it takes O(n) time. Then iterate in `for` loop through all values `v` from 0 to k and check if value `v` is inside dictionary (`if v in c:`) and if inside then check `if c[v] == 3:` then output this triple, this second loop will take O(k) time. Total algorithm will be exactly O(n + k).

Comment: I'm having some troubles since its my first time working with dictionaries and hearing about them. I'm trying to understand that if I do another  `for` loops outside the function, first I find the maximum number in my list with `k=max(list)` then I do a for loop that runs from 1 to k. will this make the time complexity O(n+k)?       about dictionaries, I understood that we're searching counters v that are equal to 3, but what if the list length was longer than k, wouldn't it be a problem?  apart from all that I really appreciate your help and patience with me.

Comment: @Pwaol First dictionary-based counting loop takes O(n) time. Then min or max computation based on full list takes another O(n) time. Then for loop over all k values takes O(k) time. In total O(n + k) time. I decided to write for you such [algorithm here online](https://cutt.ly/MhCzlOq) that takes exactly O(n + k) time. If k is bigger than n then time is O(n + k) if k is always smaller than n then time is O(n), because O(n + k) for k < n is actually O(n). Also if k > n always then O(n + k) is simply O(k). Whatever is bigger n or k then O(n + k) time is simply O(bigger_of_n_or_k).

Comment: Thanks so much arty, it took me a while to understand it but now I get what you did. the only question thats troubling me is k, what is k? I thought its the range of numbers from 0 to the maximum number in the list, but I see you took the k to be the difference between the maximum number and the minimum number in the list, was this on purpose?, also I thought about adding a loop to sort the numbers in the triples list from smallest integer to biggest integer, to reach O(n+k).

Comment: @Pwaol I did a loop from kmin to kmax just to solve generic task, when we don't know that numbers start from 0, numbers may be negative for example in general case, also if to start loop from kmin then we get more efficient algorithm. If you're sure that your numbers are from 0 to k-1 then change my `range(kmin, kmax + 1)` just to `range(kmax + 1)` in this case `k = kmax + 1`. Also if you want to sort your numbers then complexity will be not O(n + k) but O(n log n + k), because sorting algorithm is O(n log n) complexity, so finally your complexity is bigger than O(n + k) to say strictly.

Comment: ohh I see, thanks for your help, the question actually asks to sort the triplets list too, so I will try to do it without changing the time complexity, is there anyway to check time complexity accurately so I make sure I didn't mess up?

Comment: @Pwaol I implemented sorting-based algorithm with O(n log n) complexity [here online](https://cutt.ly/fhCvWrN). I have idea how to use sorting to do O(n + k) exactly, I'll code this algorithm for you now, this needs a special kind of sorting.

Comment: @Pwaol [Look here](https://cutt.ly/ChCvXDr) I implemented counting-sorting algorithm which is exactly O(n + k).

Comment: Brilliant answer, took me a while to understand again, thanks so much for your help, as I feel that I slacked since you gave me the answer, I would be happy if you could tell me where can I find some similar exercises in order to make sure that I am able to reach these solutions in the future. you taught me alot of new stuff and tricks today, honestly thank you very much.

Comment: @Pwaol I don't know any special book about such exercises or algorithms, probably these kind of knowledges come with time. But there are sites which allow you to practice similar tasks, like [hackerrank.com](https://www.hackerrank.com), [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/), [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/), [topcoder.com](https://www.topcoder.com/challenges/), [coderbyte](https://www.coderbyte.com/challenges), [project-euler](https://projecteuler.net/archives), [spoj](https://www.spoj.com/problems/classical/), [acm.timus.ru](https://acm.timus.ru/problemset.aspx), etc.